# Tips to prevent errors in execution of time-based workflow?

Tags: scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow, locking

Our implementation includes a number of time-based workflow rules.  Due to high volume, we have been experiencing frequent occasions where execution of updates to some records in the time-based workflow queue fails with the error "Salesforce workflow could not perform a pending action".  We investigated with Salesforce and they pinpointed the issue to record locking.

We may convert our approach to use scheduled Apex rather than time-based workflow rules, but would prefer not to have to do this conversion unless really necessary.  Has anyone else run into this, and have any tips & tricks to offer which might reduce the chances of having record locking affect the execution of time-based workflow?

Comment: I have run into this but unfortunately, haven't had time to try and figure out a way to prevent it from happening. I just go in and manually update the records that were missed. But if it helps to know you are not alone, well you are not alone!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of workflow is causing your errors. Most time based workflow typically involves tasks. If you're using it for something else, that's likely why you're not able to perform the updates. Looking at what happens when the the record no longer meets the criteria would be the important part of the equation to consider. If it  doesn't, can the workflow be retracted or restarted? If not, that's an obvious issue.